# Check if strings are intersting

Tags: algorithms

Two strings S and T are said to be interseting if there are two non-empty strings A and B such that S = A+B and T = B+A.How to find if two strings are intersting or not?

EXAMPLE : if S="tokyo" and T="kyoto", then the pair (S,T) is interesting, because we can find A="to" and B="kyo".

Comment: By this, do you mean "design an algorithm to check if the condition holds"? How efficient do you need this algorithm to be?

Comment: One idea: Compute hash for $T$ and $O(n)$ hash values for modified $S$. Examine cases where the hash values are equal.

Comment: @IgorRivin yeah...i want algorithm for this. (If possible a piece of code in c++ language).It should just do it in one read of both strings i think

Comment: @user2943324 could u please explain it in context of above example?

Comment: It was a bad idea, never mind. I think Igor's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for $ S$ in $T+T.$ That should be quick enough.